# VBScript: redirecting output from command line with arguments

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the "process list" from mysql and output it into a file for logging purposes. here is the VBScript code:

```
 Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
 Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
 Dim fso, ts, fileObj, TextLine

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 FileName = "mysqlprocess.log"

 If Not(fso.FileExists(FileName)) Then
    'File does not exist'
fso.CreateTextFile FileName
 End If

 'Obtain a file object for the file'
  Set fileObj = fso.GetFile(FileName)

 ' Open a text stream for output.
 Set ts = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending, TristateUseDefault)

 ' Write to the text stream.
 ts.WriteLine Date & " - " & Time
 ts.WriteLine

 Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 'comspec = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%")'

 Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql -u root -ppassword mydatabase -t -e 'show processlist;'")
 Do
     line = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
     strOutput = strOutput & line & vbcrlf
 Loop While Not objExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream

 ts.WriteLine strOutput

 ts.WriteLine "=============================================="
 ts.Close
```

And here is what is written into the mysqlprocesslist.log file:

5/06/2013 - 1:08:58 PM

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.15, for Win64 (x86)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
[.............]

So this is working as if it was not reading out the arguments. I tried to change the Exec line to include spaces, but this didn't work either:

```
 Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql" & " -u root -ppassword mydatabase -t -e 'show processlist;'")
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I got it right, the problem was with the single quote syntax:

```
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql -u root -ppassword mydatabase -t -e 'show processlist;'")
```

The correct one is:

```
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql -u root -ppassword mydatabase -t -e ""show processlist;""")
```